# Finding subsets of dates withing List<Tuple<date,double>>

Tags: c#

In C#, I have a `List<Tuple<DateTime,Double>>` named timeseries.  I'm trying to calculate some basic statistics (averages and whatnot) and subsets of dates from timeseries.  For example, I want to calculate the average over:

- One Month (ie. Today to 1 month ago)
- Three Months
- Six Months
- One Year

My thought was to use a loop to go through each of the above and remove dates from the timeseries to then reduce the data just Tuple that I'm interested.  This seems pretty inefficient though...

Does anyone have any thoughts on how I could do this?  Would LINQ do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: How many dates do you have?  If it's not a lot then efficiency likely doesn't matter as even an inefficient approach won't take long.

Comment: yea, it's pretty small.  It will likely be under 600.

Comment: @keynesiancross Then just do whatever works and is easiest to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is for one month, the same with 3 or 6 months:

```
var dataForOneMonth = dataList.Where(t => t.Item1 >= DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1) 
                           && t.Item1 <= DateTime.Now);


 var sum = dataForOneMonth.Sum(t => t.Item2);
 var avg = dataForOneMonth.Average(t => t.Item2);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why Linq couldn't do this (although this doesn't mean it's the best approach). Something like this, off the top of my head, might work:

```
// Assign some tuple data to 'dataList'
List<Tuple<DateTime,Double>> dataList = SomeTupleData

// Filter all the rows to just the dates desired.
dataList
  .Where(row => row.Item1 >= startDate && row.Item1 <= endDate)
  .Average(row => row.Item2)
```